# Temperature range for canned goods

Tags: food-preservation, canning

Temperature range for canned goods?

The question is about home canning in glass but I suspect the same applies to commercial metal cans.

I have read under 70 F and bad things happen fast at 100 F.

Is there a lower bound?  If they freeze will they survive.

I want to set up an outdoor kitchen that I would use for home canning and cooking. I would like to build a cabinet for the canned goods (one reason is to keep them out of the sun).  It will only get to less than freezing maybe a couple times a year and doubt they would freeze.

Is the lower bound above freezing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that outdoors would be the best place to store your home canned goods. Even in an insulated cabinet, that the sun doesn't hit, the temperature in the cabinet may rise in the summer above recommended levels. Also, humidity may rust your lids(and bands, if you leave them on).

From [Nation Center for Home Food Preservation](https://nchfp.uga.edu/how/store/store_home_canned.html)

> Label and date the jars and store them in a clean, cool, dark, dry place. For best quality, store between 50 and 70 °F. Also for best quality, can no more food than you will use within a year unless directions for a specific food provide other advice.
>
> Do not store jars above 95° F or near hot pipes, a range, a furnace, in an uninsulated attic, or in direct sunlight. Under these conditions, food will lose quality in a few weeks or months and may spoil. Dampness may corrode metal lids, break seals, and allow recontamination and spoilage.
>
> Accidental freezing of canned foods will not cause spoilage unless jars become unsealed and recontaminated. However, freezing and thawing may soften food. If jars must be stored where they may freeze, wrap them in newspapers, place them in heavy cartons, and cover with more newspapers and blankets.

Comment: Not if the highs are less than 70 F.  Low humidity.

Comment: @paparazzo you didn’t say where you were, so I went with a general answer. I would still make sure the sun wasn’t hitting the cabinet since it could raise the temperature inside above the air temperature.

Comment: I will be in a shaded outdoor kitchen.